# How to get Page Header not Section Headers in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm struggling to get the page header from a word document with hundreds of pages,
it has different headers

my code:

```
pageHeader = wdDoc.Sections(pageNumber).Headers(1).Range.Text
```

this code gets the headers for the Section but not spefic header of the page. Therefor there are chances that the header is incorrect.

my only input is the pageNumber

context: I'm importing word document to excel and each word page has tables, these tables are associated with their unique number apparently placed in the header of each page, so different pages can have different header

Comment: The correct index value for `Sections` is *not* a page number. This isn't how Word works with headers/footers. It isn't possible to read the exact text of the header/footer for a particular page. You need to describe in more detail (in the question, please) what you need to do with the information coming from the Word document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something along the lines of:

```
wdDoc.Range.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=i).Sections.First.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text
```

where i is the page number.

**Note:** The above code assumes you're using early binding. For late binding, use something along the lines of:

```
wdDoc.Range.GoTo(1, i).Sections.First.Headers(1).Range.Text
```

Comment: will try this out